# Does x * x (and similar) lead to constraint violation if x has enumerated type?

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer, arithmetic-expressions

C11, 6.2.5 Types, 18:

> Integer and floating types are collectively called *arithmetic types*.

C11, 6.2.5 Types, 16:

> An *enumeration* comprises a set of named integer constant values. Each distinct
> enumeration constitutes a different *enumerated type*.

C11, 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators, Constraints, 2 (emphasis added):

> Each of the operands shall have **arithmetic type**.

Sample code:

```
enum E { a };
int f(enum E x)
{
        return x * x;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ icc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ cl t235.c /std:c11 /Za /c
<nothing>
```

Question: Does `x * x` (and similar) lead to constraint violation?

As I understand, the operand `x` has *enumerated type*, not *arithmetic type*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerated types are integer types, which are arithmetic types. There is no constraint violation.

From n1548: 6.2.5.17

> The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are
> collectively called integer types.

"Integer types" are arithmetic types, as you noted.

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood what constraint you are referring.

According to the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 17 The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and **the
> enumerated types are collectively called integer types**. The integer
> and real floating types are collectively called real types.

The operator * is defined for integer types because they are a part of arithmetic types.

> 18 **Integer** and floating types are collectively called arithmetic
> types.

Only you need to bear in mind that there is a difference between applying the operator to objects of an enumeration type and to its enumerators. Enumerators in C have always the type `int` while the compatible integer type of enumerations is implementation defined.

Consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum E { a = 1 };
    
    enum E e = a;
    
    printf( "e * -1 < 0 is %d\n", e * -1 < 0);
    printf( "a * -1 < 0 is %d\n", a * -1 < 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output can be

```
e * -1 < 0 is 0
a * -1 < 0 is 1
```

Opposite to C in C++ enumerations are not integral types however unscoped enumerations can be promoted to integral types.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, interesting. Indeed, per implementation an enumerated type can be compatible with, for example, an unsigned integer type.

Comment: Re: "what constraint you are referring": "Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type" (C11, 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators, Constraints, 2).

Comment: @pmor You are right. As the enumerators are positive numbers  the enumeration  can have the type  unsigned int. So due to the arithmetic usual conversions the signed int type sill be converted to the unsigned int type.